# Groovy: escape curly braces inside string

Tags: string, groovy, escaping, curly-braces

I am coding in groovy and am trying to return some javascript. Here is the issue I need to return a string that contains a curly brace and of course groovy reads that as an error. Here is a simple example:

```
${ i == 0 ? '{' : '}, {' }
```

I want to return either:
    {
or
    }, {
plan and simple.

```
${ i == 0 ? 'should be left brace' : "should be right brace coma left brace" }
```

Can curly braces be escaped, similar to escaping quotes?
I have tried:

```
${ i == 0 ? '\{' : '\}, \{' }
```

and

```
${ i == 0 ? '{{' : '}}, {{' }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that problem occurs in a GSP page. The error you probably get should look similar to this one:

```
expecting ''', found '\n' @ line 57, column 80.
it) { return i == 0 ? '{' : ' })
```

One solution is to use the Unicode representation for left and right curly braces:

```
${ i == 0 ? "\u007B" : "\u007D,\u007B" }
```

Comment: +1. Yes, the parsing of GStrings in GStringTemplateEngine is much less sophisticated than the compiler's method. It just looks for the next "}" so there is no way to escape it.

Comment: Yes its a .gsp page. I tried the unicode example above. It returned nothing as in no characters.

Comment: could you provide the context where you did use the ${} expression?

Comment: its inside a <g:each> on a grails view

Comment: Ok, there was some dumbness on my part. PEOPLE DON'T FORGET IT MUST BE DOUBLE QUOTES!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
def i = 1
assert "},{" == "${i == 0 ? '{' : '},{'}"
```